# Recyclerview onclicklistener into another recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to build something like when the user clicks on one of the store lists, it goes into a storefront where it lists its items with recyclerview but it showed "java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()" when I run it. And I'm using firebase to recall all the data

Store list Activity:

```
public class StoreListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//declaring variables
EditText searchStore;
RecyclerView storeList;
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<StoreHelperClass> storeData;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<StoreHelperClass, StoreViewHolder> adapter;
DatabaseReference reference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_store_list);

    //firebase
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Stores");

    //hooks
    searchStore = findViewById(R.id.searchStore);
    storeList = findViewById(R.id.storeList);
    storeList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    storeList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    //load data
    LoadData("");

    searchStore.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString()!=null) {
                LoadData(s.toString());
            }
            else {
                LoadData("");
            }
        }
    });

}

private void LoadData(String data) {

    Query query = reference.orderByChild("search").startAt(data.toUpperCase()).endAt(data.toLowerCase() + "\uf88f");

    storeData = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<StoreHelperClass>().setQuery(query, StoreHelperClass.class).build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<StoreHelperClass, StoreViewHolder>(storeData) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StoreViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull StoreHelperClass model) {

            holder.storeName.setText(model.getStoreName());
            holder.storeRate.setText(model.getRating());
            holder.storeDistance.setText(model.getDistance());
            Picasso.get().load(model.getImages()).into(holder.storePic);
            holder.storeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(StoreListActivity.this, StoreFrontActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("storeKey",getRef(position).getKey());
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public StoreViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.store_list_layout, parent, false);
            return new StoreViewHolder(v);
        }
    };
    adapter.startListening();
    storeList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

And StoreFront Activity

```
public class StoreFrontActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//declaring variables
TextView storeName, storeDistance;
RecyclerView categoriesList;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CategoryHelperClass, CategoryViewHolder> adapter;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ItemHelperClass, ItemViewHolder> adapter2;
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<CategoryHelperClass> categoryOption;
DatabaseReference reference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_store_front);

    //firebase
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Stores");

    //hooks
    storeName = findViewById(R.id.storeName);
    storeDistance = findViewById((R.id.storeDis));
    manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    categoriesList = findViewById(R.id.itemCatalog);
    categoriesList.setLayoutManager(manager);

    String storeKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("storeKey");
    reference.child(storeKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.exists())
            {
                String strNames = snapshot.child("storeName").getValue().toString();
                String strDistances = snapshot.child("distance").getValue().toString();
                storeName.setText(strNames);
                storeDistance.setText(strDistances);
                LoadData();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

private void LoadData(){
    categoryOption = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<CategoryHelperClass>().setQuery(reference,CategoryHelperClass.class).build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CategoryHelperClass, CategoryViewHolder>(categoryOption) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull CategoryHelperClass model) {

            holder.categoriesName.setText(model.getCategoryName());
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ItemHelperClass> options2 = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemHelperClass>().
                    setQuery(reference.child(model.getCategoryName()).child("itemCategories"),ItemHelperClass.class).build();

            adapter2 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ItemHelperClass, ItemViewHolder>(options2) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ItemHelperClass model) {
                    holder.itemName.setText(model.getItemName());
                    holder.itemPrice.setText(model.getItemPrice());
                    Picasso.get().load(model.getItemImages()).into(holder.itemImage);

                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View v2= LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_layout,parent,false);
                    return new ItemViewHolder(v2);
                }
            };
            adapter2.startListening();
            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            holder.categoriesLayout.setAdapter(adapter2);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_item_category,parent,false);
            return new CategoryViewHolder(v);
        }
    };
    adapter.startListening();
    categoriesList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please add stack trace?

Comment: Try not using `LoadData("")`, that's the source of the error ig

Comment: At which particular line of code are getting that error?

Comment: Perhaps, in here `intent.putExtra("storeKey",getRef(position).getKey());`, `getRef(position).getKey()` returning null